# css display:block and its opposite

Tags: html, css

To separate one line of text onto two lines I am using:

```
<p>Line one <span>line two</span></p>   
p span { 
     display:block
}
```

But on the mobile version of my page I would like to remove that block on the element so that it displays all on one line. Is there an opposite of display:block? Am I using the correct approach to accomplish this?

Comment: there isn't an "opposite", technically, but you might be thinking of `display:inline`. That's the default value

Comment: are you using media queries? if so just leave the `span` blank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want them to be in one line but still blocks/boxes (so to have width and height) use this:

```
display:inline-block;
```

If you want them to be replaced as text (so as sequence of characters) then use

```
display:inline;
```

By default span elements have `display:inline;` styling.

Answer (score 1):

With opposite I assume you want to hide it? That'll be `display: none;`
Making display none on the span will hide the whole line completely, though. Try it like this:

```
<p>Line one <br/>line two</p>
```

And in the media query for mobile

```
p br { 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The display property specifies the display behavior & visibility of an element.

opposite of display block is

```
display : none;
```

it used for deleting and recreating them.

You can also consider `inline-block` :

inline-block elements inline elements but they have a width and a height.